How to Mock GraphServiceClient for Testing CreateUser Method in AzureAdAccessManager?
I am working on a unit test for the AzureAdAccessManager class, which interacts with Microsoft Graph API using the GraphServiceClient. Below is my implementation of the AzureAdAccessManager class and the relevant test case code.
AzureAdAccessManager Implementation:
public AzureAdAccessManager(IConfiguration configuration, ILog logger, IAccessTokenService accessTokenService, IOptions<ConfidentialClientApplicationOptions> options)
{
    _configuration = configuration;
    _logger = logger;
    _accessTokenService = accessTokenService;
    _option = options;
}

public virtual Task<GraphServiceClient> GetGraphClient()
{
    var clientId = _option.Value.ClientId;
    var tenantId = _option.Value.TenantId;
    var clientSecret = _option.Value.ClientSecret;

    var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
    var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" });

    return Task.FromResult(graphServiceClient);
}

public async Task<User> CreateUser(User user)
{
    _logger.LogInfo("AzureAdAccessManager : Starting method CreateUser.");
    var graphClient = await GetGraphClient();
    return await graphClient.Users.PostAsync(user);`enter code here`
}

Title: How to Mock GraphServiceClient for Testing CreateUser Method in AzureAdAccessManager?
Description:
I am working on a unit test for the AzureAdAccessManager class, which interacts with Microsoft Graph API using the GraphServiceClient. Below is my implementation of the AzureAdAccessManager class and the relevant test case code.
AzureAdAccessManager Implementation:
public AzureAdAccessManager(
    IConfiguration configuration, 
    ILog logger, 
    IAccessTokenService accessTokenService, 
    IOptions<ConfidentialClientApplicationOptions> options)
{
    _configuration = configuration;
    _logger = logger;
    _accessTokenService = accessTokenService;
    _option = options;
}

public virtual Task<GraphServiceClient> GetGraphClient()
{
    var clientId = _option.Value.ClientId;
    var tenantId = _option.Value.TenantId;
    var clientSecret = _option.Value.ClientSecret;

    var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
    var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
        clientSecretCredential, 
        new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" });

    return Task.FromResult(graphServiceClient);
}


public async Task<User> CreateUser(User user)
{
    _logger.LogInfo("AzureAdAccessManager : Starting method CreateUser.");
    var graphClient = await GetGraphClient();
    return await graphClient.Users.PostAsync(user);
}

Test Case Implementation:
protected override Mock<GraphServiceClient> OnBuild()
{
    var graphServiceClientMock = new Mock<GraphServiceClient>();
    return graphServiceClientMock;
}

Error

System.NotSupportedException: Unsupported expression: ... =>
....PostAsync(It.IsAny(), null, CancellationToken)
Non-overridable members (here: UsersRequestBuilder.PostAsync) may not
be used in setup/verification expressions.


I think you need to mock IRequestAdapter that is passed to a constructor of a GraphServiceClient. Setup mockRequestAdapter to return User object.
Example of a unit test:
var mockRequestAdapter = new Mock<IRequestAdapter>();
var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(mockRequestAdapter.Object);

var userToCreate = new User { Id = "id", DisplayName = "test" };

mockRequestAdapter.Setup(
    adapter => adapter.SendAsync(It.IsAny<RequestInformation>(), User.CreateFromDiscriminatorValue, It.IsAny<Dictionary<string, ParsableFactory<IParsable>>>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
).ReturnsAsync(userToCreate);

mockRequestAdapter.Setup(
    adapter => adapter.SerializationWriterFactory.GetSerializationWriter(It.IsAny<string>())
).Returns(new JsonSerializationWriter());

var userResponse = await graphServiceClient.Users.PostAsync(userToCreate);

Assert.Equal(userToCreate, userResponse);

